# How do you delete node from octopus deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

If you rename the VM where octopus deploy is installed, you will get the following error.

> You are using the trial version of Octopus Deploy, which only allows 1
>   active node. You currently have 2 active nodes.". Previous
>   installation has been shutdown

That is because Octopus Deploy thinks you have 2 nodes.

[image]

How do you delete the old node?

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a gui, so you will need to do this from the command line.

Inside the MSSQL Database is a table called 'OctopusServerNode'. The table only contains a list of the Server nodes. Removing the line from that database will remove the node.

Install the [`mssql` command line utility](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joseph_idzioreks_blog/2015/10/26/azure-sql-database-cli-on-mac-os-x/).

```
npm install -g sql-cli
```

Connect to the sql server (Replace everything inside brackets <>)

```
mssql -s octopusxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net -u <sqladminusername> -p '<password>' -d OctopusDeploy -e
```

List all Octopus Servers

```
SELECT * FROM OctopusServerNode
```

Verify that you can select the correct row from the table. If the node you wanted to delete was called 'foobar', you would run the following

```
SELECT * FROM OctopusServerNode WHERE Name = 'foobar'
```

Once you are 100% positive you are selecting just the 1 node that you want to delete, go ahead and delete it.

```
DELETE FROM OctopusServerNode WHERE Name = 'foobar'
```

Run the selet statement again to verify that the row was deleted from the table and exit.

```
exit()
```